# How to use multiple keys when sorting?

Tags: python, sorting

There's this list that I want to sort:

```
table = [("A", 5, 3), ("B", 5, 6), ("C", 3, 1)]
```

Inside each tuple, let's call the elements `name`, `points`, `ex`, in that order.

I want to sort that list by descending order of points, that's simple enough.

But if points are the same for 2 tuples, I'll sort those by ascending order of ex.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: just return them all in a tuple in the order you want them used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "*[sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)*" built-in function with custom ordering function. If you want to make values to be ordered descendently, it's sufficient to use negatives of the same values.

```
sorted(table, key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[2]))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 5, 3), ('B', 5, 6), ('C', 3, 1)]
```

Comment: if `points` are same then ascending order of `ex`. In your answer it is descending of `ex`

Comment: Messed up with what index was what, thanks!